# Change the default scan filter policy bluetooth linux

Tags: linux, filter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm working on a bluetooth project using bluez on linux. I know that Bluez communicates with the kernel using the mgmt socket, the mgmt commands are then translated by the kernel to HCI commands (please correct me it's otherwise). The issue I have is when I call the bluez function startDiscovery() through Dbus, the mgmt command "start Discovery" is sent to kernel, and then the kernel translates it to HCI commands "set scan parameters" and "set scan enable". the "set scan parameters" HCI command uses the default scan filter policy, i.e 0x00. I'd like to change that to 0x01 so I can do active scannig based on whitelist. I didn't find any command in the btmgmt interface to change the the default value. Do you have any idea how to change that without having to deal with the linux kernel source code ?
Note: I'm already on the latest version of bluez, i.e 5.64

Answer (score 0):

If I use the `bluetoothctl` tool (which uses the D-Bus API) to connect to a device with the following command:

```
[bluetooth]# connect E5:10:5E:37:11:2D
```

Then looking in the `btmon` log I see that the device is added to the white list and the filter policy is set to `01`

```
< HCI Command: LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) plen 7                                                                 #89 [hci0] 27.585652
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                     #90 [hci0] 27.586456
      LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                                      #91 [hci0] 27.586526
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                     #92 [hci0] 27.587041
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                          #93 [hci0] 27.587091
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                     #94 [hci0] 27.587723
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
```

Likewise if I use the `btmgmt` tool (which used the mgmt API) to add a device:

```
[mgmt]# add-device -a 1 -t 2 E5:10:5E:37:11:2D
```

In the `btmon` log I can see the device is added to the white list and filter policy is changed.

```
@ MGMT Command: Add Device (0x0033) plen 8                                                                                {0x0003} [hci0] 483.522029
        LE Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
        Action: Allow incoming connection (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Device Added (0x001a) plen 8                                                                                {0x0002} [hci0] 483.522065
        LE Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
        Action: Allow incoming connection (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Device Added (0x001a) plen 8                                                                                {0x0001} [hci0] 483.522065
        LE Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
        Action: Allow incoming connection (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Unknown (0x002a) plen 15                                                                                    {0x0003} [hci0] 483.522088
        2d 11 37 5e 10 e5 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     -.7^........... 
@ MGMT Event: Unknown (0x002a) plen 15                                                                                    {0x0002} [hci0] 483.522088
        2d 11 37 5e 10 e5 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     -.7^........... 
@ MGMT Event: Unknown (0x002a) plen 15                                                                                    {0x0001} [hci0] 483.522088
        2d 11 37 5e 10 e5 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     -.7^........... 
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                           {0x0003} [hci0] 483.522114
      Add Device (0x0033) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
< HCI Command: LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) plen 7                                                                #89 [hci0] 483.522585
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: E5:10:5E:37:11:2D (Static)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                    #90 [hci0] 483.523249
      LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                                     #91 [hci0] 483.523362
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                    #92 [hci0] 483.523860
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                         #93 [hci0] 483.523905
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                    #94 [hci0] 483.524561
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
```

There is a good presentation at https://youtu.be/VMDyebKT5c4 that explains what is done in the user space and kernel.

It is also worth noting that the term whitelist is being phased out as documented in the Bluetooth SIG's Appropriate Language
Mapping Tables located at:

https://specificationrefs.bluetooth.com/language-mapping/Appropriate_Language_Mapping_Table.pdf

I think the relevant section is:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the feedback. What you said is true. However, I think this way of doing things is suitable for connectable devices and I can not add many devices bcz it enables the scan, plus I prefer an active scan in my use case. My issue is I don't seem to find a way to do active scan using the whitelist, or at least use some kind of filtering to filter exported devices on bluez. To my knowledge, the pattern in setFilter() call can be used to filter expoted devices, but only base on one pattern. what about if I want to filter multiple devices that don't share the same prefix (pattern) ?